# Представление в памяти структуры c++

Tags: c++

Каково представление в памяти данной структуры?

```
struct S { 
  constexpr static unsigned x = -1; 
  S&& s; 
}
```

Comment: за `unsigned x = -1` хочется немножко по рукам дать...

Comment: IMHO может зависеть от реализации, так что в отладчике надо смотреть.

Comment: `constexpr static` - вообще заинлайниться может более чем. `S&&` - это ссылка - размер `size_t`?

Comment: Это задание из экзаменационных билетов) Разве х не будет при этом иметь свое максимальное значение в unsigned?

Comment: @Frostah будет. Но всё равно некрасиво.

Comment: `x ` точно будет вне структуры, даже если компилятор сдуру выделит под него память - потому что он `static`. Так что все, что будет храниться - ссылка, а она физически, как я понимаю, всегда есть адрес... Значит, вся структура будет состоять из одного адреса.

Comment: `Sizeof(S)` выдает 8

Comment: @Frostah на 64 бита)

Comment: Получается, что адрес занимает 64 бита?

Comment: @Frostah на 32 бита будет 32) битность системы это и есть размер указателя (ооочень грубо).

Comment: Круто) Благодарю

Comment: @Frostah На 32-битном VC++2015 дает 4. Ну, как я и говорил :)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)